# Java Data Structure - Complex Array

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to code in Java a complex data structure that in C++ might be called an "array of structure" or in Pascal an "array of record".

An example of its use would be building the program for a credit card company that would like to keep track of all its customers and their credit balances, etc., as such:  (I realize I have the datatypes on the wrong side of the colon)

```
array[1000] of  
     {  CustomerName  : String ; 
        AccountNo     : Integer ;
        Balance       : Float ;
        Overdue       : Boolean     }
```

I've been reading through 3 different Java Manuals,  one I have at home
(Y.Liang), and two other ones at Barnes and Noble, including "SAMS Learn Java in 14 days". The SAMS Java manual mentions an "array of Objects" about halfway through the book, where he's discussing ArrayList and HashTable, but that doesn't seem to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class to encapsulate your data:

```
public class Customer {
    private String name;
    private int accountNo;
    private flaot balance;
    private boolean isOverdue;

    // Getters, setters, constructor...
}
```

And then you can create an array of it:

```
Custoer[] customers = new Customer[1000];
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on the answer above, create your class to hold your data (such as public class Customer referenced before).

Then instead of a fixed-length array you can use java.util.ArrayList.

```
java.util.ArrayList<Customer> list = new java.util.ArrayList<Customer>();
Customer newObject = new Customer();
... populate newObject.
list.add(newObject);
```

If you want to iterate the list, you can do this (or a number of other ways):

```
for (Customer customer: list) {
...
}
```

ArrayList is referred to as a Container. C++'s stdlib has its own style of containers, so this should be familiar to you. The advantage is that it's dynamic in nature - the list can grow if you make more, and you can do list.size() to see how many items are in it.

This is far more common than using a Customer[] array.